# My iPhone calendar icon missing.

Tags: iphone

How do  I retrieve my iPhone calendar? The icon disappeared off my screen. I thought this was a permanent icon? Help!

Comment: If it got moved into a folder, search for it with Spotlight and the name of the folder it's in will be shown on the right side of the search result. There is a way to remove the icons of permanent apps that's undone by rebooting, so if you can't find it in a folder, try rebooting.

Answer (score 2):

If you somehow did uninstall the Calendar app from your phone like my father did, an easy way to get it back is to have someone text you a date, like "December 1st". This will automatically be converted to a link, which you can tap, which will then open a prompt with a message asking if you'd like to re-install Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the app store and load the Calendar app...